# Remove header in journalctl results

Tags: centos, rhel, systemd-journald

Sample Command run on RHEL 7:

```
$ journalctl -n1
-- Logs begin at Tue 2015-09-29 17:44:38 PDT, end at Thu 2015-10-22 10:51:35 PDT. --
Oct 22 10:46:00 linuxdev sshd[9730]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user tbenz9 by (uid=0)
```

How do I hide the first line of the output so it only reports the log messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the option `--quiet`:

```
journalctl --quiet -n1
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems the man page description should be more thorough on what the flag does.  It doesn't mention anything about the header.

Comment: @tbenz9, [fixed](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/20d936ba8167f4224cd01903e97fa852c00c0988) :)